# Why is my async '.then' not waiting until fetch is completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

From what I understand about promises I should be able to run something in a '.then' after the promise returns and expect that a fetch is completed at that time.  But for some reason I cannot get a page to reload AFTER the fetch is done to a node.js app.

```
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    }).then(window.location.reload(false));
```

I even tried putting a timer on it to see if just needed more time on the server side, but it still runs immediately, ignoring the timer:

```
    .then(function() {
        window.location.reload(false)
    }, 5000);
```

Could this be from how the fetch interacts with a node.js app or am I missing something in my implementation?

Comment: The version with the actual callback function will work, you just seem to have confused then with setTimeout.

Comment: On your then. What does your console log? Or the problem comes only with the window reload?

Comment: `I even tried putting a timer` where did you read that you could add a timer as a second argument to `then`?  `then` does not provide such a functionality?

Comment: I did get confused with setTimeout, thank you.  @ panoskarajohn the problem is only that the reload runs to quickly.  I would expect the fetch to be complete before it runs.

Comment: i mean... technically, your second snippet should have worked. The `5000` would have not done anything, but the first callback would have been called *after* the fetch was complete. How are you determining that the second one isn't working?

Comment: I suspect, that `fetch` results in an error. To track down the problem you should only write `fetch("http://localhost:3000/").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })` and check the console of the browser, to see if you see any errors.

Comment: `I don't see any errors in the console and see the promise being returned` you might not see an error because the reload happens, so you should for now get rid of the reload. If you really don't see any error, then the error is more likely on the server-side handling the request.

Comment: I have the node.js app outputting everything as well and do not see any errors.  The node is sending a query to a small database. Do you think it is possible the DB is simply not finished updating yet back to the frontend webpage I'm refreshing?

Comment: As querying a DB also involves async code handling and as you obviously have some problems with getting that right in the browser, it is for sure possible that you have similar problems server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that when you set `window.location.reload(false)` after the then, it is being called at that same moment, in order to wait for the function to trigger, you need to pass an empty function and it will be triggered after.

```js
fetch("https://api.github.com/orgs/nodejs").then(response => {
  console.log("we get response")
  console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
}).then(() => {
  console.log("we move...")
  // the line is commented so it doesn't  loop infinitely.
  //window.location.reload(false)
});
```

what you are doing is something like this:

you are executing the function inmediatly instead of waiting for the resolve.

```js
const newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('foo')
    resolve(true);
  }, 1500);
});

newPromise.then(console.log("anything"))
```

the correct way should be:

```js
const newPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('foo')
    resolve(true);
  }, 1500);
});

newPromise.then(()=>{
  console.log("anything")
})
```

Comment: The sentence `the problem is that when you set window.location.reload(false) after the then` is kinda misleading as for `.then(window.location.reload(false));` the `window.location.reload(false)`  is not place after the `.then`. `reload` is called and its result is passed as argument to `then`.

Comment: I explained better the solution and the problem.

Comment: I misunderstood the answer at first, but i still don't think it's all that useful. My reasoning is the op has supposedly already tried a similar solution, and it didn't work (see attempt 2). so either there's some other problem at play here that hasn't been presented in the question yet, or the OP has falsely determined that their second attempt didn't work.

Comment: no, @user400654 the problem with the 2nd attemp is what @t.niese stated on the question, he tried to put a timer on a function on the `then` clause and that approach does not exist, therefore it wont work.

Comment: @PrinceHernandez except... it does in fact work. https://jsfiddle.net/kamr8407/

Comment: @PrinceHernandez the `.then(function() {
        window.location.reload(false)
    }, 5000);` will have the same effect as writing `.then(function() {
        window.location.reload(false)
    });` as `then`  expects as arguments `fulfillment-callback, rejection-callback`, so `5000` is passed as `rejection-callback` and just ignored, because it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

`then` expects a function, not a statement. Try `.then(() => window.location.reload(false))`. A statement will just be executed when evaluated, so you end up with your page reloading (I'm guessing infinitely?)

Comment: @notsodev what do you mean with it does not work? If you write it that way the `reload` is called after `fetch("http://localhost:3000/")` is finished. How do you know that it does not work?

Comment: If that does call it after, I guess that the function on the server side is taking longer than I expected. I do not see the changes that the fetch causes on reload

Comment: @notsodev maybe you get an error (maybe you request `http://localhost:3000/` from a differnt domain like `http://localhost/` resulting in a CORS error). `.catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    }).then(() => window.location.reload(false));`  does a reload even if an error occures, because you catch the error before then `then` with the reload.

Comment: @t.niese I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the node.js app to accept from where I'm calling it.  I don't see any errors in the console and see the promise being returned

Answer (score -3):

As we know the concept of "**Promise**" from ES5 standards in which it makes code non-blocking and has callback function in itself like .then() or .catch() for error handling.
Here you trying to make code sync so here is the way you can use async-await  as fetch() return promise resolve or reject to some value unlike

Eg;

```
const employeeList = async () => {
fetchResult  = await fetch("https://api-dev.abc/employees");
return fetchResult;
}
console.log(employeeList());
```

Await used in async pause then the synchronous flow of execution and wait until promise come with resolved or reject value. Above fetchResult will have either resolved value or rejected value or say error. If we are not using async-await then we have to use .then() callback function for accessing value resolved or rejected by Promise.
Await is used to await callback hell problem in async code of ECMA.

Comment: Promises don't make code non-blocking if the code chunk within the `then` callback is blocking, then it stays blocking. Promises allows to manage the order of code execution for async results easier.

Comment: `await fetchResultTemp  = fetch("https://api-dev.abc/employees");` is invalid. And why do you use `then` if you already suggest using `async`/`await`?

Comment: Using `then` allows to get the resolved value, that's true. Within an `async` function you can use `await` to get the resolved value, instead of using `then` allowing to get rid of the chaining. `const data  = await fetch("https://api-dev.abc/employees");`. the `fetchResultTemp.then((data) => { return data;})` is a no opt. as you jsut pass `data`trough without doing something. Morover `print(employeeList());` passes a Promise to `print` that resolves to `undefined` as you don't return anything from then function stored in `employeeList`.